# Why QGraphicsView is not shown

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsscene

I have the following codes in my Qt project with the following main:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    Widget w;
    w.show();

   return a.exec();
}
```

The class Widget is a QWidget object with the following constructor:

```
Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent)
: QWidget(parent)
{
   m_Scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
   QGraphicsLinearLayout* layout = new 
   QGraphicsLinearLayout(Qt::Orientation::Vertical);
   for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
   {
      std::string name = "m_" + std::to_string(i);
      GraphicsTextItem* item = new GraphicsTextItem(nullptr, QString(name.c_str()));
      layout->addItem(item);
   }
   QGraphicsWidget* list = new QGraphicsWidget;
   list->setPos(0,0);
   list->setLayout(layout);
   m_Scene->addItem(list);

   QGraphicsView* view = new QGraphicsView(this);
   view->setScene(m_Scene);

   // Why one of these lines must be uncommented?
   //m_Scene->setSceneRect(0, 0, 1920, 768);
   //QVBoxLayout *ttopLayout = new QVBoxLayout;
   //ttopLayout->addWidget(view);
   //setLayout(ttopLayout);
  }
```

GraphicsTextItem is just a QGraphicsWidget for displaying text:

```
class GraphicsTextItem : public QGraphicsWidget
{
public:
    QString m_Name;
    QColor m_Color;
public:
    GraphicsTextItem(QGraphicsItem * parent = nullptr, const QString& name = QString());
    void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget) override;
{
    Q_UNUSED(option)
    Q_UNUSED(widget)

    QFont font("Times", 10);
    painter->setFont(font);
    painter->setPen(m_Color);
    painter->drawText(0, 0, m_Name);
}

};
```

My question is that why my scene is not shown. I must either define a SceneRect or define a layout on my widget?

Comment: How are you adding Widget to its parent?

Comment: @drescherjm Widget is my main widget it has no parent. I instantiate it in my main and then I call show.

Comment: @drescherjm I added more code to the question for clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made an even shorter MCVE for demonstration:

```
#include <QtWidgets>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  qDebug() << "Qt Version:" << QT_VERSION_STR;
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  QWidget qWinMain;
  qWinMain.resize(320, 240);
  QFrame qFrm(&qWinMain);
  qFrm.setFrameStyle(QFrame::Box | QFrame::Raised);
  qFrm.setLineWidth(0);
  qFrm.setMidLineWidth(1);
  qWinMain.show();
  return app.exec();
}
```

compiled and started in [cygwin64](http://www.cygwin.org). This is how it looks:

[image: Snapshot of MCVE (layout missing)]

1. There is a main window (with window manager decoration).
2. There is a child `QFrame`.
3. The child `QFrame` is "pressed" into the upper left corner.

How comes?

What `QWidget` does ensure: Child widgets are rendered (in front) when `QWidget` is rendered.

What `QWidget` is not (directly) responsible for: Layouting child widgets.

For this, a layout manager has to be plugged in:

```
#include <QtWidgets>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  qDebug() << "Qt Version:" << QT_VERSION_STR;
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  QWidget qWinMain;
  qWinMain.resize(320, 240);
  QVBoxLayout qVBox(&qWinMain);
  QFrame qFrm(&qWinMain);
  qFrm.setFrameStyle(QFrame::Box | QFrame::Raised);
  qFrm.setLineWidth(0);
  qFrm.setMidLineWidth(1);
  qVBox.addWidget(&qFrm);
  qWinMain.show();
  return app.exec();
}
```

compiled and started again in [cygwin64](http://www.cygwin.org). This is how it looks:

[image: Snapshot of MCVE (with layout)]

Now, the `QFrame qFrm` is filling the `QWidget qWinMain` nicely. Resize events received in `qWinMain` will be forwarded to the layout manager `qVBox` which will re-layout the children of `qWinMain` (i.e. `qFrm`) again.

---

I strongly believe OP's `GraphicsView` is just not visible because it has no minimal size requirement. (It's just to small to be visible.)

Hence, adding a layout manager ensures that the `GraphicsView` fills the parent widget client area. Resizing the contents of `GraphicsView` (by `m_Scene->setSceneRect(0, 0, 1920, 768);`) is yet another option to fix this, albeit the worse one.

---

Finally, the link to Qt Doc.: [**Layout Management**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html).

> ### Layout Management
>
> The Qt layout system provides a simple and powerful way of automatically arranging child widgets within a widget to ensure that they make good use of the available space.
>
> #### Introduction
>
> Qt includes a set of layout management classes that are used to describe how widgets are laid out in an application's user interface. These layouts automatically position and resize widgets when the amount of space available for them changes, ensuring that they are consistently arranged and that the user interface as a whole remains usable.
>
> All QWidget subclasses can use layouts to manage their children. The [QWidget::setLayout()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setLayout) function applies a layout to a widget. When a layout is set on a widget in this way, it takes charge of the following tasks:
>
> - Positioning of child widgets
> - Sensible default sizes for windows
> - Sensible minimum sizes for windows
> - Resize handling
> - Automatic updates when contents change:
>
>   - Font size, text or other contents of child widgets
>   - Hiding or showing a child widget
>   - Removal of child widgets

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response. So you think that the minimum size is not defined for a QGraphicsView but the sizeHint() used by the layout is defined so that it resizes?

Comment: @Minee I must admit that I never tried to nest `QWidget`s into each other without using some kind of `QLayout`. I used your question to make a counter-example (for my own curiosity as well). Thus, I'm not sure how `minimumSize()` and `sizeHint()` are considered beyond layouting with `QLayout`.